# Returning a Row Count for a DataRow in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

My script is populating a datarow from a stored procedure in SQL Server. I then reference specific columns in this datarow throughout the script. What I'm trying to do is add functionality that takes action X if the row count = 0, action Y if the row count = 1, and action Z if the row count > 1.

```
-- PowerShell script snippet

# $MyResult is populated earlier; 
# GetType() returns Name=DataRow, BaseType=System.Object

# this works
ForEach ($MyRow In $MyResult) {

    $MyFile = Get-Content $MyRow.FileName
    # do other cool stuff
}

# this is what I'm trying to do, but doesn't work
If ($MyResult.Count -eq 0) {
    # do something
}
ElseIf ($MyResult.Count -eq 1) {
    # do something else
}
Else {
    # do this instead
}
```

I can get $MyResult.Count to work if I'm using an array, but then I can't reference $MyRow.FileName directly.

This is probably pretty simple, but I'm new to PowerShell and object-oriented languages. I've tried searching this site, The Scripting Guy's blog, and Google, but I haven't been able to find anything that shows me how to do this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check `$MyResult | Get-Member` to see which methods and properties the object provides.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Ansgar. I should have mentioned I looked at those, and I found I could do $MyResult.ItemArray.Count, but it returned a count of all columns and rows. So while it works for finding out if Count > 0, it doesn't help for finding out if Count = 1.

Comment: Does $MyResult.rows.Count work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this question gets a lot of views, so I wanted to post how I handled this. :)

Basically, the fix for me was to change the method I was using to execute a query on SQL Server. I switched to Chad Miller's Invoke-SqlCmd2 script: [TechNet: Invoke-SqlCmd2](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/7985b7ef-ed89-4dfd-b02a-433cc4e30894#content), i.e.

```
# --------------- 
# this code works
# ---------------

# Register the function
. .\Invoke-Sqlcmd2.ps1

# make SQL Server call & store results to an array, $MyResults
[array]$MyResults = Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -Serve
rInstance "(local)" -Query "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.databases;"

If ($MyResult -eq $null) {
    # do something
}
ElseIf ($MyResult.Count -eq 1) {
    # do something else
}
Else {
    # do this instead
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It has everything to do with how you populate `$MyResult`.  If you query the database like

```
$MyResult = @( << code that returns results from database >> )
```

that is, enclosing the code that returns your dataset/datatable from the database within `@( ... )`, then number of rows returned will be easily checked using `$MyResult.count`.

Your original code should work as-is if you populate $MyResult this way.

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is old, but if someone else finds it on Google, this should work also on PS V5:

Replace `$MyResult.Count` with: `($MyResult | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count)`

For Example:
`If (($MyResult | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count) -eq 0)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with PS and SQL, but I'll try to provide an answer for you. If you're object `$myresult` is a `datarow`-object, it means you only got the one row. If the results are empty, then `$myresult` will usually be null.

If you get one or more rows, you can put them in an array and count it. However, if your `$myresult` are null, and you put it in an array it will still count as one, so we need to watch out for that. Try this:

```
If ($MyResult -eq $null) {
    # do something if no rows
}
Else If (@($MyResult).Count -eq 1) {
    # do something else if there are 1 rows.
    # The cast to array was only in the if-test, 
    # so you can reach the object with $myresult.
}
Else {
    # do this if there are multiple rows.
}
```