# How do I count the number of rows in a dataset and add that to a variable?

Tags: powershell

I have a dataset that can vary on the number of lines/records within it.

Using a foreach loop, I step through the dataset pulling information out of the line and sending an email.

When there are no lines or more then one line all is fine, however when the script tries to run and there is one line only the array marker is acting like a subscript.  Here is the section of code,

```
foreach ($Row in $dt)
{
Write-Output "Currently Proccessing record" $dt.SessionID[$i]
    $BT1 = $dt.SessionID[$i]
}
```

So if my SessionID = "FRED" and there is only one line in the dataset, I will only get the first character "F" rather then "FRED".

Anyone able to point me to an example of how to manage this issue?

Comment: `($dt | Measure-Object).Count` will tell you the number of items in the table.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Thanks, I'll get the hang of this PowerShell some day :)

Comment: `$dt.count`  will give you the number of records in the dataset.

Comment: @Harsh thanks that's useful as well :)

Comment: The issue around your `SessionID` is not completely clear. Would you be able to add the definition of the table and some sample data? I can work out an example for you.

Comment: Is this a .Net dataset with a datatables property or an array of custom objects? Also you have an `$i` that is never set. Are you wanting a `for` loop instead of your `foreach`? Otherwise $Row is never used.

Answer (score 0):

As @Harsh said, use `$dt.count` to get the count.

Some more info on a similar post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395510/returning-a-row-count-for-a-datarow-in-powershell)